# Filter for number range : AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a form with some input types like text, radio etc. When I submit the form, it lists the entered details below the form(used template and directive for this). I want to do filter in age , ie, the number input type, such that when I give an age range, it should filter profiles with corresponding age range. Here is the plunker :

http://plnkr.co/edit/h8p8rtZuAhCoKClUjgE9?p=preview

```
    <table border="1" style="width:200px">
   <tr>
       <td> <div>Name : {{  formElement.name }} </div><br> </td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td> <div>Age : {{ formElement.age }}</div><br> </td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: You need to use a filter on `ngRepeat`. So you need find a way to share the `filterModel` object between your directives (either using a parent scope or a service). Note though, that it is highly unusual to have the filtering logic separated from the display logic that the filter applies to. It would be a better idea to place the filtering-related stuff in the `fasterDisplay` directive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could write a custom filter function that filter by range on a particular field:

```
$scope.byRange = function (fieldName, minValue, maxValue) {
  if (minValue === undefined) minValue = Number.MIN_VALUE;
  if (maxValue === undefined) maxValue = Number.MAX_VALUE;

  return function predicateFunc(item) {
    return minValue <= item[fieldName] && item[fieldName] <= maxValue;
  };
};
```

and use it in `ng-repeat` expression:

```
<div ng-repeat="formElement in formElements | filter:byRange('age', filterModelMin.age, filterModelMax.age)">
```

Note that the `filterModelMin.age` and `filterModelMax.age` can be used directly in `fasterDisplay` directive because both `fasterForm` and `fasterDisplay` do not have their own scope.

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/dFbBCKxSxm9RI9dwSeYR?p=preview

Comment: Am I able to use this function if I have an object containing all my filters? I'm writing an app where I'll have to filter on location and agerange, and possibly more filters. How would I go about doing this? My object looks like this: `$scope.eventsfilter = {minAge: <numberrange>, maxAge: <numberrange>, postal: <string>}` - so both the minAge and maxAge should match the range the user defines. (So if a user wants to filter events from age 21-27, it also matches events for age 22-24).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a custom filter select function. In your repeat you can do:

```
<div  ng-repeat = "formElement in formElements | filter:filterAge">
```

And the following function in your controller:

```
$scope.filterAge = function(val) {
  return (val.age > MIN_AGE && val.age < MAX_AGE);
};
```

However, in your case you have the required values (`MIN_AGE` and `MAX_AGE`) in a different directive and in a different scope. You could share this values to the correct directive by either using a service or storing the values in the parent scope and passing the reference into your directives.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on runTarm's answer. This will allow you to use nested values with the dot operator:

```
$scope.byRange = function (fieldName, minValue, maxValue) {
  if (minValue === undefined) minValue = Number.MIN_VALUE;
  if (maxValue === undefined) maxValue = Number.MAX_VALUE;

  return function predicateFunc(item) {
    var keys = fieldName.split('.');
    var val = item;
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      val = val[keys[i]];
    }

    return minValue <= val && val <= maxValue;
  };
};
```

used in your ng-repeat expression like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="formElement in formElements | filter:byRange('person.age', filterModelMin.age, filterModelMax.age)">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, this solution works better because after deleting the min and maxlikes inputs all the collection will be returned.

```js
$scope.byRange = function (fieldName, minLikes, maxLikes) {
                    if (minLikes === undefined || maxLikes === undefined || maxLikes === null || minLikes === null) {
                        return function predicateFunctionTwo(item) {
                            return item[fieldName];
                        }
                    } else {
                        return function predicateFunc(item) {
                        return minLikes <= item[fieldName] && item[fieldName] <= maxLikes;
                      };
                  }
                }
```

```html
<div class="content" ng-repeat="data in addingPlaceService | filter:byRange('likes', minLikes, maxLikes) track by $index">
```